# On publishing a click once installer through install from web, the installer does not appear on the webpage

Tags: installation

I am creating a clickonce installer using the deployment strategy of Install from the Web or network share, on one of my project. I am learning how to use click once installers. When i publish my project it gets succeeded. i gave the URL of my website that i had created through google so that anyone can install from that URL. After publish gets succeeded the URL should be launched automatically but it is not. Moreover. When i check my website and in it that page whose URL i had given, there is nothing there. No installer. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a while since I did this, but I'm fairly sure that you have to upload the files manually.

The installer needs the location so it can build the web page etc. All the files should be in an output folder in your project.

**EDIT:** I've just checked and the output folder is the one you specify on the first step of the Publish Wizard. If you specify a local folder the files will be put there for you to FTP to your website later.  You can also specify a remote address as and FTP or HTTP location (which I'd forgotten when I posted my original answer). You'll have to enter the user name and password for connecting to the remote location later in the process.

Answer (score 1):

- Right Click on Publishing Project
- Click Properties
- Click "Publish"
- In "Publishing Folder Location" is anything set there?
- Click the button with ellipsis (...) to the right of the combobox
- Click "FTP Site" (not Remote site, as this needs FrontPage extensions)
- Enter the Server information, Directory (that you have access to), keep it as passive mode, uncheck the Anonymous option and put in the valid FTP instructions.

Click Open, and Republish. All should work 100% with this.

If not, have a look in your `wwwroot/` folder and find the application information (if it's there) and you will have to manually upload the files.

---

EDIT for comment:

The website that you are uploading to, does it have FTP access? Meaning a place that you would upload file to for display on the website, even like your html content? (`index.html` etc.)

If not, you will need to get these details from your website hosting provider and fill in the appropriate fields for the FTP upload.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I don't get the FTP site part and the point you stated after that. i am a newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio 2008? The default behaviour of deploying a "publish.htm" page has changed.

Bring up your project's properties and switch to the "Publish" tab. Click the "Options" button and switch to the "Deployment" section of the dialog. You'll see by default that the "Deployment web page" TextBox is empty. You'll need to give that a value and also check the "Automatically generate deployment web page after every publish" CheckBox.

I've taken to filling that in with "default.htm" so that whichever folder you deploy your app into will have the ClickOnce publish page as its default page.

Comment: All that you mentioned about filling the text box and checking the check boxes is done. Still no results. Please help.